# On how views should get their variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a world of best practices, when do you let the view inherit the instance variables of the controller, and when do you explicitly pass them in in the locals hash?

Comment: Even though view and the partials called from that view will have access to instance variables set in the controller, I pass `locals` to the partial so that the partial is "like a self-contained method with arguments". When I need to render that partial from a totally different controller, I know that the partial does not depend on any other variable other than what was passed into it as a local.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any instance variables you define in your controller will automatically propagate to the view, so there's no need to pass them in explicitly. This works for not just your initial view, but also any partials rendered in the process.

You'll want to send in `:locals` variables when you're calling the same partial but need it to render different things that can't be accommodated with `:object` or `:collection`.

Here's an example of improperly using instance variables:

```
# Bad form
<%- @foo = 'example1' %>
<%= render(:partial => 'bar') %>
<%- @foo = 'example2' %>
<%= render(:partial => 'bar') %>
```

A better way is this:

```
<%= render(:partial => 'bar', :locals => { :foo => 'example1' }) %>
<%= render(:partial => 'bar', :locals => { :foo => 'example2' }) %>
```

The difference is that you'll see the variable in the partial as `foo` instead of `@foo`. Keep in mind that local variables may be undefined unless they are passed in which can cause trouble, so test thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to set variables in your controllers.

You shouldn't pass them from contoller because they will be visible automatically

```
#your_controller
@name = "Pedro"

#your view
Hello, <%= @name %>!
```